# How to stop CSS/HTML navigation menu wrapping at different resolutions?

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, word-wrap

I am new to CSS but have played around with various other languages over the years.  I have successfully added a navigation bar to my website but when viewed in a smaller window or lower resolution the bar wraps itself. I have spent quite a few hours looking around the internet and tried to modify the code in ways which has helped other people but am yet to find a solution.  Ideally what I want is for it to re-size as the resolution or window size changes but if that is too difficult or can't be done, just locking the size so the user has to scroll across would also be OK.

I have uploaded a copy of the html and CSS to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpor4wkb/) (I am sure it will be spaghetti code to experienced programmers as I learnt as I went).

I have put in a random Youtube image where the real image will go (same size though), all the text is random but the layout for the bar is the same and so is the smaller logo buttons on the right which all link to facebook.

Any help at all would be appreciated. If you need any more details I will check this regularly and will give as much information as possible!!

Thanks again for any possible help.

**The CSS code is:**

```
/* ----- CSS Nav Menu Styling ----- */
#cssnav { 
border: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
font: $(tabs.font); /* Template Designer - Change Font Type, Size, Etc */
color: $(tabs.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Size */
margin-top: 0px;

}

#cssnav ul {
background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
height: 40px; /* Change Height of Menu */
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
white-space: nowrap;

}

#cssnav li {
float: none; /* none = centre */
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 0px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#cssnav li a {
background: white repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
display: block;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
font: $(tabs.font); /* Template Designer - Change Font Type, Size, Etc */
text-decoration: none;

}

#cssnav > ul > li > a {
color: $(tabs.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Color */
}

#cssnav ul ul a { 
color: $(tabs.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Color */
}

#cssnav li > a:hover, #cssnav ul li:hover {
color: $(tabs.selected.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Color on Hover */
background-color: $(tabs.selected.background.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Background on Hover */
text-decoration: none;
}

#cssnav li ul {
background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
display: none;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
position: absolute;
width: 160px; /* Change Width Of DropDown Menu */
z-index:9999;
}

#cssnav li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

#cssnav li li {
background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Background */
display: block;
float: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 200px; /* Change Width Of DropDown Menu */
}

#cssnav li:hover li a {
background: #FFFFFF; /* Template Designer - Change Background of Link on Hover */
}

#cssnav li ul a {
display: block;
height: auto;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
}

#cssnav li ul a:hover, #cssnav li ul li:hover > a {
color: $(tabs.selected.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Text Color on Hover */
background-color: $(tabs.selected.background.color); /* Template Designer - Change Background on Hover */
border: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}



.navleft {float:left} .navright {float:right;} .tabs-inner .widget ul {margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;}

body .navbar { height: 0px; }


/*change background colour here to modify a lot of navbar*/
.tabs-inner .widget ul, .tabs-inner .widget li a, .tabs-inner .section:first-child ul { background: white; border: 0px;}
#navigationbar {width: 100%; height: 96px; background: white repeat-x scroll 0 -800px; _background-image: none; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 150px; z-index: 999; width:75%;}
```

**The HTML code is as follows:**

```
<div id="navigationbar">

<ul id="cssnav" class="navleft">

<img src="http://alpineskin.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/youtube-logo-small.jpg" height="80" width="300" />

</ul>

<ul id="cssnav" class="navright">

<li class="active"><a href='http://www.google.com'>Home</a></li>
<li class="sub"><a href='LINK'>About</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pmf dpfkf</a></li>
<li><a href='URL LINK TO LABEL/WEBSITE/PAGE'>pkf dpfdkf</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="sub"><a href='LINK'>Extras</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pdfkdf</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pdfdfp fopdff fdopkf</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pokef ofkdpf fopk</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pokdsf</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="sub"><a href='LINK'>pkedpf</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>poksfd</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com'>pkp</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pkdpdfk</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pip</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>ppjpp</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>perwp</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>ipfjipfipj</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="sub"><a href='LINK'>pffp</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pdjfdspfjd</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pdfdpfjd</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>opsdfdfopdf</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>psdofdsfpfsdp</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="last"><a href='http://www.google.com'>dsopdfop</a>
</li>



<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<!-- ADD MORE ICONS HERE -->



</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a media query to css. Yours was a bit long to go through so I just done a quick example changing the background, You can change whatever you like in the query.. Resize to under 400px and the li background will change.added min-width to the navigation bar as well to stop it wrapping

```css
#navigationbar ul li{list-style-type:none;display:inline-block;}
#navigationbar ul li ul{display:none;}
#navigationbar ul li:hover ul{display:block;position:absolute;}
#navigationbar ul li:hover ul li{display:block;}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    ul li{
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
  #navigationbar ul{min-width:700px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="navigationbar">

<ul id="cssnav" class="navleft">

<img src="http://alpineskin.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/youtube-logo-small.jpg" height="80" width="300" />

</ul>

<ul id="cssnav" class="navright">

<li class="active"><a href='http://www.google.com'>Home</a></li>
<li class="sub"><a href='LINK'>About</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pmf dpfkf</a></li>
<li><a href='URL LINK TO LABEL/WEBSITE/PAGE'>pkf dpfdkf</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="sub"><a href='LINK'>Extras</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pdfkdf</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pdfdfp fopdff fdopkf</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pokef ofkdpf fopk</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pokdsf</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="sub"><a href='LINK'>pkedpf</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>poksfd</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com'>pkp</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pkdpdfk</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pip</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>ppjpp</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>perwp</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>ipfjipfipj</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="sub"><a href='LINK'>pffp</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pdjfdspfjd</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>pdfdpfjd</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>opsdfdfopdf</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.google.com'>psdofdsfpfsdp</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="last"><a href='http://www.google.com'>dsopdfop</a>
</li>



<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="blank" title="DESCRIPTION OF LINK/WEBSITE"> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_black-128.png" border="0" height="20" width="20"/></a></li>
<!-- ADD MORE ICONS HERE -->



</ul></div>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work on the snippet, although it worked in snippet editor, I'll add a fiddle aswell.

Comment: [HERE JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nhn0sdn2/), resize to <400px to see background color change ( done to show when the media query kicks in )  and min-width to stop bar wrapping.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy help! Being new to this it will take me a while to go through what you have done but will report back after.

Comment: just try adding `@media screen and( max-width: 500ppx){#cssnav ul{min-width:500px;}}` to your css and see what happens. I'm off out now so I'll be back later

Comment: I have added this code and also played around in JSFiddle but no joy. I [think] you had an error in your code by placing 500ppx which I replaced with 500px but this still did not work.  I am using Blogger which has widths defined earlier on in the template, could there be something that is interfering?

Comment: I have played around a bit and I feel like my issue lies with problems around my display parameters in each class.  Unfortunately I do not have enough experience to debug it (when to use inline-block and block etc) but will continue to play around and hopefully it will eventually click. :)

Comment: yes that was an error on my part, meant px. to find out if blogger or something else is interfering put the style inline direct on the ul tag like so `<ul id="cssnav" class="navleft" style="min-width:500px">` and see if the stops it wrapping, inline styles will take priority

Comment: I tried putting this in the HTML but didn't make a difference. I will have time this afternoon to play around a bit more and go over everything you have said to try and get this to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
First if all correction to your HTML. You have used 'cssnav' as id multiple times so please try to implement the functionality without same id. 

To be specific to your requirement, add min-width to menu element and adjust the position through media query to the menu element. I have added sample position to your code in link http://jsfiddle.net/tyebufov/.

Like this you can position the menu element in various resolutions as per your requirement.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Using your code, the menu no longer wraps which is what I want, but in doing this it pushes it off the screen and is no longer reachable, not even via scroll bar on the bottom of the page or anything. With Billy's suggestion in JSFiddle (which I haven't actually been able to successfully implement into my page yet), when the window gets too small, the menu doesn't wrap but you are able to scroll across to get to the other buttons.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Have you tried with Left positon variations?

Comment: I can play around with the positions but there is a point when the window still becomes too small and the bar goes off the screen. This can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tyebufov/) when you modify the windows width of the result window. With this [Billy's suggestions](http://jsfiddle.net/nhn0sdn2/) when the window gets too small it creates the slider to scroll across.

Comment: Yes Billy's suggestion is right. Please include this in your CSS and then test it on browser instead of JSfiddle. You will be able to see scroll.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help!! I will continue to try Billy's advice.